# Error when trying to import multipe csv files into pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-import

I am trying to read several csv files from a directory into pandas and concatenate them into one big DataFrame but I have this error:

```
OSError: Initializing from file failed
```

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:/Users/chris/Downloads/Séance2/horodateurs-transactions-de-  paiement' 
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
transac = pd.DataFrame()
li = []

for filename in all_files:
   df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
   li.append(df)

transac = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

I don't know why it doesn't work. I tried to solve the problem by using chmod but anything has changed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSError: Initializing from file failed on csv in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50552404/oserror-initializing-from-file-failed-on-csv-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into same kind of problem. It turned out the files didn't have any permission and pandas was not showing proper error message.

`ls -lh
total 152M
-rw-rw-r-- 1 iamsam iamsam 3.4K Nov  6 21:34 quora_insincere_question_GUSE+LSTM.ipynb
---------- 1 iamsam iamsam  34M Feb  6  2019 test.csv
---------- 1 iamsam iamsam 119M Oct 30  2018 train.csv`

Once I gave the read permission the, it did work well.

run this command on linux :  `chmod 700 filename OR chmod 700 -R directoryname (to change for all the files in that directory.)`

After this pd.read_csv() should work fine.