# Import an excel csv file in python

Tags: python, excel, csv, import

I am currently struggling to import an excel-csv file to python. I'm sure my problem is very easy to solve, but I'm quite new to programming in python.

The code I used:

```
train1 = pd.read_csv(r"D:\Foldername1\Foldername2\data.csv")
```

Then I get this kind of error:

```
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 697, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source

OSError: Initializing from file failed
```

I thought about the need to add something like sep=',' but this didn't work either. So I'm kinda helpless at the moment.
Thank you very much already! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OSError: Initializing from file failed on csv in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50552404/oserror-initializing-from-file-failed-on-csv-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
train1 = pd.read_csv(r"D:\Foldername1\Foldername2\data.csv", engine='python')
```

If raises Permission denied, then give read permission to your file.