# How to over come the OS Error in mac while reading pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, oserror

I use Jupyter on my MacBook Pro (macOS Catalina) and when I use pandas to read a CSV file, after the read command, I get an OS error. How do I resolve this?

This is how the error is displayed:

```
import pandas as pd
r_filenameCSV='/Users/manubharathmurali/Documents/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv'      
csv_read=pd.read_csv (r_filenameCSV)
csv_read
```

[This is how the error is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ce180.png)
[Pic 2 of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsDs3.png)

After the 3rd line of code OS error is shown.

Comment: It would be useful to see the whole error stack: can you scroll down and take further screenshots?

Comment: Are you maybe missing the `r` ahead of your `r_filename`?

Comment: @Giorgio I've Updated the further error screenshots

Comment: @MarkSetchell I did check on what you've told and it seems to right. and other suggestions ?

Comment: Perhaps you CSV file has no read permissions, like this answer to another question suggests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52283966/3272066

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because `Python` cannot find the path and therefore you need to change your working directory. You can do this with the **Operating system interface** in `Python`.

Change your working directory using `os.chdir(path)` For more `methods` with the `Python os` see the docs [Click here to read](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)

```
import os
import pandas as pd

os.chdir("/Users/manubharathmurali/Documents")

#confirm the path directory
print(os.getcwd())

csv_read = pd.read_csv("Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv")

print(csv_read)
```

Comment: this is the error that's popping with the code you helped me with:- ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Can I see the directory? Can you send a screenshot? Or whats the name of the csv file?

Comment: It cannot find the file "Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv" in that directory? Kindly confirm the name of the file