# Cannot open a dataframe in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python and have learnt the basics. Tried to open a .csv file in my Jupyter Notebook but receiving an OSError when I run it. Tried entering the root address too but to no avail.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("vgsales.csv")
df
```

> ERROR :
> OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> 1 import pandas as pd
> ----> 2 df = pd.read_csv("vgsales.csv")
> 3 df
> OSError: Initializing from file failed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52283966/4551984 might be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OSError: Initializing from file failed on csv in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50552404/oserror-initializing-from-file-failed-on-csv-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

The solutions for this error may be

1. Try to give the complete path name, which the directory where the file is present.
2. Make sure that there is not space after the .csv extension
3. Do not simply name the file with the extension .csv , we should convert the file to the .csv extension. Mostly in windows it will be in .xlsx extension.