# pandas read_csv producing "IOError: Initializing from file failed" error. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, pandas, macos

I have not been able to get pandas read_csv function to work on Mac. It does not matter how the file path is configured, or what csv file I am trying to use (I have used multiple files). It always results in IOError: Initializing from file failed. I have no clue what to try. This is the format I am using.

df = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/me/Documents/file.csv')

I have tried changing the working directory and using df = pd.read_csv('file.csv'), but this produces the same error.

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50552404/oserror-initializing-from-file-failed-on-csv-in-pandas may be

Comment: nothing in there worked for me. And I have the problem on every .csv file I try and load.

Comment: Which directory is your python file in?

Comment: figured it out. .py file was in the default .spyder folder. Moved it to my documents and it worked fine. Does anyone know why it was an issue running it from the default folder? I used the full filepath both times, so not sure why running it from the default folder caused problems.