# Why doesn't Python want to read pictures?

Tags: scikit-learn

I don’t understand why my program doesn’t read pictures. I tried many different ways, but they only solved a small part of the problems. The main one remained - OSError: Initializing from file failed.

Here is what the program shows after execution (full text):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sanch\Downloads\test.py", line 123, in <module>
    train_data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\sanch\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\tensorflow-for-poets-2-master\\tf_files\\test_data", delimiter=',', nrows=nRowsRead)
  File "C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 685, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 457, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 895, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1135, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1917, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 382, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 693, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
OSError: Initializing from file failed
```

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  # For Basic ploting
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler  # Preprocessing
from sklearn import preprocessing  # Preprocessing
from random import seed
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB  # import gaussian naive bayes model
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier  # import Decision tree classifier
from sklearn import metrics  # Import scikit - learn metrics module for accuracy calculation
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt# plotting
import numpy as np  # linear algebra
import os  # accessing directory structure
import pandas as pd  # data processing, CSV file I / O(e.g.pd.read_csv)

for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk("C:\\Users\\sanch\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\tensorflow-for-poets-2-master\\tf_files\\test_data"):
    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname))


def create_model(lyrs=[8], act='linear', opt='Adam', dr=0.0):
    # set random seed for reproducibility
    seed(42)
    tf.random.set_seed(42)
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    # create first hidden layer
    model.add(tf.keras.Dense(lyrs[0], input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation=act))
    # create additional hidden layers
    for i in range(1, len(lyrs)):
        model.add(tf.keras.Dense(lyrs[i], activation=act))
        # add dropout, default is none
    model.add(tf.keras.Dropout(dr))
    # create output layer
    model.add(tf.keras.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))  # output layer
    model.complete(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


def create_model(lyrs=[5], act='linear', opt='Adam', dr=0.0):
    # set random seed for reproducibility
    seed(42)
    tf.random.set_seed(42)
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    # create first hidden layer
    model.add(tf.keras.Dense(lyrs[0], input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation=act))
    # create additional hidden layers
    for i in range(1, len(lyrs)):
        model.add(tf.keras.Dense(lyrs[i], activation=act))
        # add dropout, default is none
    model.add(tf.keras.Dropout(dr))
    # create output layer
    model.add(tf.keras.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))  # output layer
    model.complete(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

    model = create_model()
    print(model.summary())

    # train model on full train set, witch 80/20 CV split
    trainig = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2, verbose=0)
    val_acc = np.mean(trainig.history['val_acc'])
    print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % ('val_acc', val_acc * 100))

    model = create_model()
    print(model.summary())

    # train model on full train set, witch 80/20 CV split
    trainig = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2, verbose=0)
    val_acc = np.mean(trainig.history['val_acc'])
    print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % ('val_acc', val_acc * 100))

def create_model(lyrs=[10], act='linear', opt='Adam', dr=0.0):
    # set random seed for reproducibility
    seed(42)
    tf.random.set_seed(42)
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    # create first hidden layer
    model.add(tf.keras.Dense(lyrs[0], input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation=act))
    # create additional hidden layers
    for i in range(1, len(lyrs)):
        model.add(tf.keras.Dense(lyrs[i], activation=act))
        # add dropout, default is none
    model.add(tf.keras.Dropout(dr))
    # create output layer
    model.add(tf.keras.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))  # output layer
    model.complete(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

    model = create_model()
    print(model.summary())

    # train model on full train set, witch 80/20 CV split
    trainig = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2, verbose=0)
    val_acc = np.mean(trainig.history['val_acc'])
    print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % ('val_acc', val_acc * 100))

    # create model
    model = tf.keras.KerasClassifier(build_nf=create_model, verbose=0)

    # define the grid search parameters
    batch_size = [16, 32, 64]
    epochs = [50, 100]
    param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, ephochs=epochs)

    # search the grid
    grid = tf.keras.GridSearchCV(estimator=model,
                                 param_grid=param_grid,
                                 cv=3,
                                 verbose=2)  # include n_jobs=-1 if you are using CPU
    grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # summarize results
    print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
    means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
    stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
    params = grid_result.cv_results_["params"]
    for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
        print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    nRowsRead = None  # specify No.of row. 'None' for whole data
    # test_mosaic.scv may have more rows in reality, but we are only loading / previewing the first 1000 rows
    train_data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\sanch\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\tensorflow-for-poets-2-master\\tf_files\\test_data", delimiter=',', nrows=nRowsRead)
    nRow, nCol = train_data.shape
    print(f'Yhere are {nRow} rows and {nCol} columns')

    X_train = train_data.drop('Label', axis=1)
    X_test = test_data.drop('Label', axis=1)
    y_train = train_data['Label']
    y_test = test_data['Label']
```

Perhaps I did not write everything correctly, I do not know. Please help, I have very little time to show this project. I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OSError: Initializing from file failed on csv in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50552404/oserror-initializing-from-file-failed-on-csv-in-pandas)

Comment: Why are there three `def create_model` definitions?

Comment: You're trying to load a CSV file called `test_data`. Should it be `test_data.csv` (with the extension)? Or does your file really not have an extension?

Comment: @MikeJack **Sorry but no***

Comment: @rickhg12hs **I use several networks in the program at once, which should show different results. Below is the function that shows the best of the results. If this is not correct and not permissible, please correct me.**

Comment: @Dillon **No, test_data it's just a folder with images in the format png**

Comment: @АлександрТрегубов pd.read_csv is not for folders, and it is not for images, it is strictly for ".csv" files. There's lots of other things that need to be pointed out, for example you never call create_model in main, you redefine it 3 times, and the last 2 would cause infinite recursion, they should have different names.

Comment: @MikeJack **Thanks for the tip, I'll try to think it over. Maybe you have any other comments?
It turns out that I cannot use several types of networks in one code at once, I need three different programs?
Thank you for helping, I hope I can fix the code.**

Comment: You can make as many definitions as you want, but when you call it the same thing, `create_model`, later definitions essential eliminate previous definitions.  Maybe you want to call them something unique? ... or just call one with different parameters?